# Are "Help me get [X] to compile!" questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Many of our migrations from Stack Overflow are questions asking for help compiling a particular piece of software (recent example: https://serverfault.com/questions/440591/error-with-internationalization-extension-while-compiling-php-5-4-8).

These questions have historically been a gray area on Server Fault - we have lots of cases where we help people by telling them "You need to install the `foolib-devel` package", but we have an equal number of cases where so little effort was put forward that we closed the question and sent the user packing.

I think the time has come to establish a consensus on "Help me with compiling stuff" questions in the context of *professional* system administration, so I put it to the mob:

- How much help should we offer?
- How much effort does the OP need to show to merit that help?

Comment: I find it faintly annoying that questions about building and installing development tools get closed as off-topic by the SO community, then to add insult to injury, migrated to somewhere wholely unsuitable. The SO FAQ allows for these questions *"but if your question generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"*. Grr.

Comment: @Kev Seems like you're bringing your beef to the wrong meta :)

Comment: @Kev: Indeed, all of the *AMP setup and debug questions that originate on SO fall into this category too along with developer environments in Type II hypervisors and on client OS.

Answer (score 20):

Questions with these attributes stay:

- The Exact Error
- The Exact Command/Sequence used to generate The Error
- Operating System (Distro, version, etc), Software being compiled
- Software that has something directly to do with servers and/or networked services

The rest, GTFO.

Comment: And I don't care if it was migrated from SO or originated here, they should be treated the same.

Comment: @MichaelHampton agreed, I've just noticed more of them coming through the migration pipeline than actually originating here.

Answer (score 4):

Compiling is part of programming and is therefore on topic for SO. No such questions should ever be migrated out of SO and any that get thrown over here should be sent straight back.

Comment: I disagree. Compiling *your own code* is certainly programming related. Compiling Apache to support specific modules isn't and could be on topic here, depending on the rest of the content.

Comment: *Could* be on topic if *started* on SF but perfectly on topic for SO and should not be migrated away from there. Compiling is compiling, no matter who wrote the ode.

Comment: I bet if you asked SO mods whether or not compiling a web server was on-topic on SO you would get a different answer. :)

Comment: It all depends on *why* you're compiling. If you want to add new feature or change default behaviour of apache or apache module, then SO *is* the place to ask the question.

Comment: If you start going down that track where do you stop? Do you then ask why you need those feature? Why don't you use a different approach to solve the same problem? No, that's all irrelevant. The "why" of it is *always* the same - you're building software. The reasons for building the software isn't a factor.