# Looking for advice on the right way/place to ask my question about compiling

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question about packaging. I was compiling multiple depending libraries into one static, and was wondering if there was a smarter and systematic way to determine compatible versions rather than just trial & error.

My question was closed as unprofessional / off-topic here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/575263/when-compiling-how-can-i-find-out-which-dependency-versions-are-known-supposed

I left a comment saying that I'm doing packaging from my profession as sysadmin, and asked what would have been a better stack exchange site to post my question, but I never got a reply.

I'm certainly not impatient or looking to violate any stackexchange rules, I'm just genuinely looking for the right way/place to ask about this.

[image]

Comment: I didn't originally see this question; if I had, I would have asked you why you were doing this at all.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3772/are-help-me-get-x-to-compile-questions-off-topic

Comment: Imho it's a general question about how to resolve compiling issues in a smarter way. It's illustrated with exact errors of a real life example.

As for why I'm packaging this static, I'm not sure if that's relevant, but I'm looking to offer a [new version of Imagemagick](https://travis-ci.org/kvz/imagemagick-static-builder) to my customers and make it an opt-in. Otherwise I would break backwards compatibility for users of the current version. I figured creating all-in-one statics would allow me to do so, without introducing new servers or e.g. Docker.

Comment: You asked it on serverfault instead of stackoverflow.  That's why it was off topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd like to put up another candidate.

Given these constraints:

- SO doesn't accept it because it's not about solving a *programming* issue, but about using tools
- SF doesn't accept it because it's about compiling software, not systems administration
- The question is about how to do this on a Unix system

It would seem to me that there is a third option, namely [unix/linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com). Their help center lists the following among their on-topic list

- Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
- Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)

So the question would seem to be entirely appropriate there. Also, there are some brilliant unix people there from whom I've learned a lot, so I'd give it a reasonable chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think we've reached consensus on it.  Can I get the question migrated to unix/linux or should I just repost it there?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is actually about compiling code and dependencies thereof, not packaging the results of the compilation. For me, this puts it firmly in SO's realm. The people there deal with compilation etc on a daily basis, as a sysadmin I might do it occasionally. They are more likely to be able to help than we are.

Comment: Thanks. I'm solving a [sysadmin problem](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6164/looking-for-advice-on-the-right-way-place-to-ask-my-question-about-compiling?noredirect=1#comment12510_6164), but I can also see how SO would make sense. 

However if that was the reason for moderation, shouldn't the question better be migrated as was done with e.g. [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process) vs locked & deleted?

Comment: @kvz: I'm only expressing my opinion, I don't recall how I voted on it but it was split 3 to 2 so the 3 won and they chose not to migrate it. It was deleted by the cleaning fairies because it was at -1 and not edited for several days - this happens to all closed and apparently abandoned questions.

Comment: @lain: Understood, I appreciate your thoughts on this

Comment: FWIW, @kvz, I don't *think* I voted on this, but if I had, I would have voted to migrate.  Since it's compiling code and dependencies, I would have considered it more of a Stack Overflow question myself.  That's also just my opinion.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard you're correct you didm't vote on it.